# Diophantine numbers?

Tags: analysis

A real number $x$ is Diophantine if for every $ε>0$ there exists $c_ε>0$ such that $|x - \frac{a}{q}| \geq \frac{c_\varepsilon}{|q|^{2+\varepsilon}}$ for every rational number $\frac{a}{q}$.
how to prove that $\sum_{1}^{n}10^{-k!}$ is not diophantine ?

Answer (score 0):

The upper limit for your sum should be $\infty$, not $n$.  Every finite sum is rational, so will have an $a,q$ such that $x=\frac aq$ and the left side of the inequality is zero.

To do the proof, your candidate number $\frac aq$ is exactly one of the finite sums.  Because the exponent $-k!$ forces the terms to be very small very fast, once somebody gives you $\epsilon, c-\epsilon$ you can find a number of terms that makes the tail of the sum very small.